# Azure Devops pipeline and Unity floating license server fails to get license on 2nd run

Tags: unity-game-engine, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

The first time I run my unity pipeline, the self-hosted agent gets the license and builds the unity project.  The project will fail its build and I suspect the task is not returning the license when it dies in the pipelines thread.

The next run of the pipeline fails to get the license and build.

There's a unity utility called unity.licensing.client.exe that supposed to return the license.

**Unity.Licensing.Client --return-floating**  (where id is the lease id)

I'm not sure where to find the lease id and I'd like to call this in a subsequent task if the previous task fails.

I'd appreciate help with that lease id.

I've rebooted all the computers involved.
In my task I've used powershell and the unity build task (consuming 2/3 licenses)